# How to create RouteUrls with databound parameters declaratively?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, url-routing, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-routing

I'm using the new Routing feature in ASP.NET 4 (Web forms, not MVC). Now I have an asp:ListView which is bound to a datasource. One of the properties is a `ClientID` which I want to use to link from the ListView items to another page. In `global.asax` I have defined a route:

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("ClientRoute",
    "MyClientPage/{ClientID}", "~/Client.aspx");
```

so that for instance `http://server/MyClientPage/2` is a valid URL if ClientID=2 exists.

In the ListView items I have an asp:HyperLink so that I can create the link:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkClient" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# "~/MyClientPage/"+Eval("ClientID") %>' >
    Go to Client details
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Although this works I would prefer to use the RouteName instead of the hardcoded route by using a RouteUrl expression. For instance with a constant ClientID=2 I could write:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkClient" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl="<%$ RouteUrl:ClientID=2,RouteName=ClientRoute %>" >
    Go to Client details
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Now I am wondering if I can combine the route expression syntax and the databinding syntax. Basically I like to replace the constant `2` above by `<%# Eval("ClientID") %>`. But doing this in a naive way...

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkClient" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl='<%$ RouteUrl:ClientID=<%# Eval("ClientID") %>,RouteName=ClientRoute %>' >
    Go to Client details
</asp:HyperLink>
```

... does not work: `<%# Eval("ClientID") %>` is not evaluated but considered as a string. Playing around with several flavors of quotation marks also didn't help so far (Parser errors in most cases).

Question: Is it possible at all what I am trying to achieve here? And if yes, what's the correct way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [System.Web.UI.Control.GetRouteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992877.aspx):

VB:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkClient" runat="server"  
    NavigateUrl='<%# GetRouteUrl("ClientRoute", New With {.ClientID = Eval("ClientID")}) %>' > 
    Go to Client details 
</asp:HyperLink>
```

C#:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkClient" runat="server"  
    NavigateUrl='<%# GetRouteUrl("ClientRoute", new {ClientID = Eval("ClientID")}) %>' > 
    Go to Client details 
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Great, works fine! I've just changed my markup using this solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note: At least in C# you need to use ' and not " for your NavigateUrl.  Just copy the examples 1 for 1 and you'll be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's basically the same as Samu Lan's solution but instead of using .net controls you could use regular HTML anchor control.

```
<a href='<%# GetRouteUrl("ClientRoute", new {ClientID = Eval("ClientID")}) %>'> 
     Go to Client details
</a>
```