# Using routes in ASP.NET Gridview Hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net

I have a Gridview with a Hyperlink column. I want to route(Navigate) using hyperlinks depending on the id value from the database.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField  DataNavigateUrlFields="id" 
                      DataNavigateUrlFormatString="product" DataTextField="pName" 
                      HeaderText="Product Name"  
       NavigateUrl='<%$ RouteUrl:id=Eval("id"), routename = ProductRoute%>' 
       />
```

This results in an error message:

> 404 page not found

How can this be fixed?
 .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create RouteUrls with databound parameters declaratively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935367/how-to-create-routeurls-with-databound-parameters-declaratively)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the link in the RowDataBound event handler in your code-behind and debug it there.